# Append data to end of human-readable file Python

Tags: python, numpy, save, append

In one run my python script calculates and returns the results for the variables A, B, C.

I would like to append the results run by run, row by row to a human-readable file. 
After the runs i, I want to read the data back as numpy.arrays of the columns.

i   | A B C

1 | 3 4 6

2 | 4 6 7

And maybe even access the row where e.g. A equals 3 specifically.

Comment: The question is ambiguous on a few counts. How large will the file grow? Depending on that the solution would be different. Also, if you are concerned about performance, it might not be the best way to maintain the data.

Comment: About 1000 runs. Would this already limit the performance?

Comment: I dont see the point of it then. It can easily fit in memory and it would be just easy enough to pickle if you want to transfer it around for any reason. For 1000 runs you could store it as a dict too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your thoughts. These two options came to my mind too but I need the mixture of both: My specific use case requires the file to be human readable - as far as I know pickling does not provide that and saving to a dictionary destroys the order. I need the data to be dropped as they need to be manipulated in other scripts before the next data is produced.

The not very elegant way I am doing it now: numpy.savetxt() to files labeled by the run, and bash "cat" applied in the end.